# Split Series by string length

Tags: python, string, pandas, split

I have more than 1M rows and want to split a Series of strings like `123456789` (length=9) into 3 Series (like MS Excel can do):

```
c1  c2  c3
123 456 789
... ... ...
```

I see `.str.split` function which needs some separator and `.str.slice` which gives only one Series at a time. Is there smth. better than this?

```
s21 = s11.str.slice(0,3)
s22 = s11.str.slice(3,6)
s23 = s11.str.slice(6,9)
```

Comment: `I want to split 1M!` is not going to take much of time, unless you are going deploy the code in production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html#pandas.Series.str.extract):

```
>>> df
         s11
0  123456789
1  987654321
>>> df['s11'].str.extract('(.{3,3})' * 3)
     0    1    2
0  123  456  789
1  987  654  321
```

Though, when something simple like [`str.slice`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.slice.html#pandas.Series.str.slice) works, it *tends* to be faster than using unnecessary regex, even if you need to call it few times manually or using a for loop.

You may do `str.slice` in one liner as in:

```
>>> df['a'], df['b'], df['c'] = map(df['s11'].str.slice, [0, 3, 6], [3, 6, 9])
>>> df
         s11    a    b    c
0  123456789  123  456  789
1  987654321  987  654  321
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you need to do is split fixed-length strings into smaller, equal-sized fixed-length strings, you can do:

```
s = "123456789"
x = [s[i:i+3] for i in range(0, 9, 3)]
```

Comment: I want to split 1M strings at a time! .) I think it'll be more time consuming than pure pandas way

Comment: Well, it depends on what you intend to do with them.  But I really don't think packing them into a list will make any appreciable difference, especially if you evaluate the range() expression outside of the loop and reuse it.  Your program will be I/O bound, not compute bound.

Comment: yeah, it's already i/o bound cause i have to read ~1.5gb of string data from ms access. At least want to process it fast